# Substitution pattern to escape quotes in vim

Tags: regex, vim, escaping

I have text with some lines contains properly escaped double quotes in strings and some not
like below:

```
bla1 "aaa"bbb"ccc" bla1
bla2 "aaa\"bbb\"ccc" bla2
```

The results after substitution should be

```
bla1 "aaa\"bbb\"ccc" bla1
bla2 "aaa\"bbb\"ccc" bla2
```

but not:

```
bla1 "aaa\"bbb\"ccc" bla1
bla2 "aaa\\"bbb\\"ccc" bla2
```

In other words it should escape the double quotes in lines where they are not escaped 
and do not touch lines which are already properly escaped

So far I got the second result with this

```
%s:\(\s".\+\)\(".\+\)\(".\+"\s\):\1\\\2\\\3:g
```

Then I've tried a negative lookbehind to tell the engine to not match 
if there is a backslash before the quotes

```
(?<!\) which in vim should be something like @<!\

%s:\(\s".\+\)\@<!\\\(".\+\)@<!\\\(".\+"\s\):\1\\\2\\\3:g
```

But I think I've got a little lost.

Note:
There is only one such string per line
The string is enclosed in double quotes and can contain double quotes inside - only this inside one should be escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said there is only 1 string on each line, you can chain substitute commands to get the result that you want. (This also leads to easier regexes in all parts of the command)

```
:%s/"\zs.*\ze"/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\\\@<!"', '\\"', 'g')
```

Explanation:

1. `:%s/"\zs.*\ze"` matches everything on the line between the first and the last quote. We use the greedy `.*` to do this. `\zs` marks the start of the match and `\ze` marks the end of the match.
2. After that we can pass the match to a second substitute command by adding `\=` to the start of the replacement. This means that the result of the expression after it will be the replacement string.

   ```
   substitute(submatch(0), '\\\@<!"', '\\"', 'g')
   ```

   `submatch(0)` is everything between the quotes. We then replace all quotes that don't have a slash  before it (`\\\@<!"`) with a `\"`.

Take a loot at `:h sub-replace-expression`, `:h /\zs` and `:h /\ze`

---

Example Input:

```
bla1     "aaa"bbb"ccc"      bla1
bla2     "aaa\"bbb\"ccc"    bla2
bla\bla3 "aaa"bbb"ccc"      bla3 
blabla4  "aaa"bbb" "BBB"ccc" bla4       
bla\bla5 "aaa"bbb" "BBB"ccc" bla5
bla\bla5 "aaa"bbb""BBB"ccc" bla5
```

Example Output:

```
bla1     "aaa\"bbb\"ccc"      bla1
bla2     "aaa\"bbb\"ccc"    bla2
bla\bla3 "aaa\"bbb\"ccc"      bla3 
blabla4  "aaa\"bbb\" \"BBB\"ccc" bla4       
bla\bla5 "aaa\"bbb\" \"BBB\"ccc" bla5
bla\bla5 "aaa\"bbb\"\"BBB\"ccc" bla5
```

Comment: Hi this answer is better than one from Jeff I've modified the input output data to show that it works even if there is multiple quotes inside a string. I'm going to accept it. There is only one small case when it will not work as I would like it to 
E.g.:
bla\bla5 "aaa"bbb""BBB"ccc" bla5
become
bla\bla5 "aaa\"bbb\""BBB\"ccc" bla5

The case is if there are two double quotes inside ""
Maybe you know how to make it work for this case too

Comment: Sorry I press enter too early Now the comment should be fine

Comment: @szydan I changed the regex in the second substitute command to use a negative look behind instead. This works when there are two quotes next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could just stick an inverse global onto one of the command you wrote already.  Now it only will apply to lines that don't contain already escaped quotes:

```
:v/\\"/s:\(\s".\+\)\(".\+\)\(".\+"\s\):\1\\\2\\\3:g
```

Comment: Seems to work. Please could you just explain more about this first part v/\\/

Comment: Check out `:h global`.  Using a `v` instead of a `g` applies the command to lines that don't match the pattern which in this case is just a backslash.

Comment: Thanks nice trick, but would fail on case like this
bla\bla3  "aaa"bbb"ccc" bla3  Where there is a back slash in blabla before the actual string

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\([^ \\]\)"\([^ ]\)/\1\\"\2/g
```

This finds quotation marks not preceded by a slash or space and not followed by a space.

Comment: Kevin this did not worked - I've added a Note to the question
The important part is that I want only to escape the double quotes which are inside a pair of double quotes, NOT all double quotes

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
%s/\([^\\]\)\("\)/\1\\\2/g
```

Comment: First, you don't need to capture the quotation mark, you know `\2` is always going to be one, and second, this will get the outer quotes too.